# Mobile check scanning and OCR based handwritten data extraction approach - Looking for recommendations

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ocr, scanning

What is the best approach for bank check scanning and OCR based data extraction in mobile apps? with a client side library alone or with client side library + a server based OCR recognition api?

Currently considering Mitek A2IA library for iOS and Android, which offers both client side alone and client side + server assisted OCR text extraction. If you have already used Mitek A2IA lib in any of your projects for check scanning please shed some lights on the approach you followed.

Thanks in advance.